# Weird output after using \to (or \rightarrow) in TexMaker

Tags: math-mode

I am having a problem with TexMaker.
When compiling the following section, it says `! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...13 is the smallest value on the path 1 \to [...]` (can't see the rest).

Source text:

```
The maximum amount of flow between 1 and 3 would hence be 13 in our example, for 13 is the smallest value on the path 1 \to 2 \to 6 \to 5 \to 3 in the Gomory-Hu-Tree.
```

pdf-output:

[image: Here's a screenshot!]

The problem is the last part, where all the words are thrown together for some reason (and also printed cursive I think). I have not worked with Latex before, so I do not have any idea what might be causing the issue, any help would be

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be `$\to$` instead of only to.

Comment: Or even `$1 \to 2 \to 6 \to 5 \to 3$`. Anyway, the point is that `\to` only works in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

> Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be $\to$ instead of only to. 
>   Or even $1 \to 2 \to 6 \to 5 \to 3$. Anyway, the point is that \to only works in math mode. –

I do not know where I messed up, but posting the question as a guest first and only then creating an account kinda forbids me to access it as OP. However, this answer is totally correct and it worked right away, so thank you to Torbjørn T.!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).